# Using Multiple And's in a Case statement instead of subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having a problem using multiple **And**'s in a **Case** statement.

My Database looks like:

```
Enrollment      Paperless      Validated
0               1              0
1               0              1
0               1              0
1               1              1
0               0              0
0               1              0
0               0              0
0               1              0
1               1              1
0               1              0
```

So my query looks like this:

```
Select
    Count(case when [Enrollment] = 1 and [Paperless] = 1 and [Validated] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Paperless]
    ,Count(case when [Enrollment] = 1 and [Paperless] = 1 and [Validated] = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as [Online_Only]
    ,Count(*) as "Total"
FROM [my_table]
```

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/61202/5

As you can see from the sql fiddle the count is always 20 in the case statements when they should be different. Am I just doing something wrong in my case statement or do i have to do them in sub-queries?

*Dave*

Comment: Is this the exact query? Because in addition to the answers provided, I noticed that your case statements are exactly the same for both `[Paperless]` and `[Online_Only]`. Additionally, the answer still stands ... use `SUM`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`COUNT` returns true regardless of the actual value. So use:

```
SUM(CASE ...)
```

instead of

```
COUNT(CASE ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other alternatives:

(1) You can use COUNT(), but drop the ELSE clause.  This will result in NULLs rather than 0s, so they won't be counted.

(2) You can also switch to math operations:

```
SELECT SUM(Enrollment*Paperless*Validated) as <whatever>,
       SUM(Enrollment*(1-PaperLess)*Validated) as <something else>
```

Personally, I often like the multiplication form, because the statement is shorter and I can more often see all the conditions without scrolling.